# 15k and 20k privileges not listed in the FAQ

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta-faq

The [FAQ on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) (and the other sites) doesn't list the [15k](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/protect-questions) and [20k](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) privileges (links to the privileges pages are for illustration).

Comment: Is this status-completed? I see them now.

Comment: @Jason Plank: On what site?

Comment: I see it on MSO and SO, bicycles.SE, and probably lots of others. http://i.imgur.com/8MuYb.png

Comment: @Jason Plank: I mean in the FAQ, not the privileges page.

Comment: they are listed, I'm going to delete this after you read my comment -- ah, my bad, you said FAQ!

Comment: You have to wear special glasses to see them.  You'll get a pair when you reach 10k.  They also allow you to see deleted questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, they are listed now in all the parent site /faq entries.